I am just starting discrete mathematics and immediately lost on a very foundational level question.
I am actually stumped on a completely basic question and hoping to get help because I feel rather defeated and alone in this endeavor to learn math.
Consider a positive integer $n$
Check all that apply:

"If $n$ is even, then $7n + 4$ is even; if $7n+4$ is even, then $n$ is even"
"If $n$ is odd, then $7n + 4$ is odd; if $7n+4$ is odd, then $n$ is odd"
"If $n$ is even, then $7n + 4$ is even; if $7n+4$ is odd, then $n$ is odd"
"If $n$ is odd, then $7n + 4$ is even; if $7n+4$ is odd, then $n$ is odd"

Well at first I thought this was:

True
False
False
True

Is this right? Why? Please can you explain in excruciating detail including the process?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The basic points:

$even + even = even$
$even + odd = odd$
$odd + odd = even$
$even \times any\ integer = even$
$odd \times odd = odd$

$7$ is odd and $4$ is even, so if $n$ is even, $7n + 4$ is even, while if $n$ is odd, $7n + 4$ is odd.
And so if $7n + 4$ is even, $n$ must be even, and if $7n + 4$ is odd, $n$ must be odd.

So then this means that I am right and I shouldn't doubt my answer? However - I highly doubt my method and understanding and I don't understand entirely how I would know other than to try all those combinations. Is that what I have to do always?

I am very lost still does this mean that only one of the answers is right? Actually I am pretty sure it is the first two now but now I am not sure because I have changed my answer 3 times.

@user284985 Think about the eight component statements. One of those statements is true if it associates an even $n$ with an even $7n+4$, or an odd $n$ with an odd $7n+4$, in either direction. Meaning 4.a and 4.b from the image are false, and the others are true. Or 4.a from the text is false, and the others are true (your text doesn't match the image). Can you then work out the truth of each combined statement?

My text is probably wrong despite my best efforts...
I think that the 8 statements are now
1.T,T 2.T,T 3. F,F 4.F,F
but at this point it is only because of what the other person said and I don't know how to know this without substituting numbers. I don't understand how you can come from a statement and make a mathematical claim like an odd x odd is odd and even x anything is even and figure something out because there are infinite numbers so how do you know?

@user284985 that's correct for 1, 2 and 4, but statements 3.a and 3.b are both associating even with even or odd with odd, so they're both true.

@user284985 as to how you can prove general statements when there are infinitely many numbers, you do it by going back to the definitions. For example, to prove $even \times anything$ is $even$, we will call our even number $a$ and our anything number $b$. Then $a$ being even means by definition it can be written as $2c$ for some integer $c$. So $a \times b$ is $2c \times b = 2bc$. But obviously $2bc$ is $2$ times an integer, so by definition it is even. So we've shown the product is even.

@user284985 We did this without assuming what our numbers are, except that $a$ is even, so this holds for all numbers, $a$ and $b$ where $a$ is even.

So then the first 3 are true and the only false one is the last one then? Because the third one is also 2 biconditional statements that are both true in and of themselves.....
I feel like I don't understand

"we will call our even number a and our anything number b. Then a being even means by definition it can be written as 2c for some integer c. So a×b is 2c×b=2bc. " This confuses me a lot primarily because I don't understand why 2c gets multiplied by b or even what these variables represent at that point. I also am very confused by the second half which is that the 2bc is 2 times an integer, where I understand what that is saying; but I don't understand the relevance to the question. it means that anything x an even is even which was one of the premises

We are trying to prove that $even \times anything= even$.  So we need to give a name to our even number.  Let's call it Fred.  But how can we know that Fred is even. Since Fred is even we know that $Fred = 2 \times something$.  Let's give a name to that "something". Let's call it Wilma.  So $Fred = 2\times Wilma$ is our even number which can be any even number. Now we need to give a name to our "anything" number. Let's call it Babar.  So we need to prove that an even Fred times any Babar is an even number. That is $Fred \times Babar = 2\times something$.  How do we show that?

Well.... $Fred = 2\times Wilma$ so $Fred \times Babar = 2\times Wilma \times Babar$ and we have to show that $2 \times Wilma \times Babar$ is $2$ times something?  Well, is it $2$ times something?  Well it is $2$ times $Wilma \times Babar$ and $Wilma \times Babar$ is something.  So yes.  An even number (which is two times one thing) times any number (which is something else) will  be two times the one thing times the something else.  As it is two times something it will be even.

Well there are many way to do it
If we want to be thoroughly thorough

If $n$ is even (okay, let $n=2m$ where $m$ is an integer.

Then $7n + 4 =7(2m)+4 = 14m + 4$.  Is that even? Well, can we divide by $2$?
$14m + 4= 2(7m + 2)$ and $7m+2$ is an integer.  So yes, $7n +4$ will always be even.

If $n$ is odd.  (okay, so $n$ is not even.  You can't divide it by $2$.  If you try to divide it by $2$ you can a remainder of $1$.  So $n=2m+1$ for some integer $m$.

So is $7n+4$ odd?  $7n+4 = 7(2m+1)4 = 14m + 7 + 4 = 14m + 11$.  Is that even?  Can we divide it by $2$?  $2m$ can be divided by $2$.  And $10$ can be.  But we will have a reminder of $1$ as $11$ is odd.
In fact.... $14m+11 = 2(7m + 5) + 1$.  THat must be odd.

if $7n +4$ is even then $n$ is even.

Well, either $7n+4$ is even or it is odd.  And $n$ is either even or odd.  If $n$ is odd. the by 2) we have $7n+4$ is odd.  But that didn't happen.  We are told by God on High that $7n+4$ is even.  So... $n$ can't be odd.  And if $n$ isn't odd it is even.
But if we want to be thoroughly thoroughly thorough....
If $7n + 4$ is even then $7n + 4 = 2m$ for some $m$.  Let's solve for $n$
$7n = 2m-4 = 2(m-2)$
$n = \frac {2(m-2)}7$.  That has to be an integer.  So $7|2(m-2)$.  But $7$ is prime.  So by Euclid's lemma $7$ must either divide $2$ or divide $m-2$.  As it doesn't divide $2$ it divides $m-2$ and $\frac{m-2}7$ is an integer.
So $n = 2\times \frac{m-2}7$ is even.
And so on.....
But this is all overkill of course.
The key things to remember is
$even \pm even = even$.
Why?  because $2m \pm 2k = 2(m\pm k)$.
$odd \pm odd = even$
Why?  because $(2m + 1) + (2k+1) = 4m + 2 = 2(2m+1)$.  And $(2m + 1)-(2m+1)=4m=2(2m)$.
$odd + even = odd$.
Why?  $(2m+1) + 2k = 2(m+k) + 1$.
And $even\times anything= even$.
Why?  $(2m)\times w = 2\times (mw)$.
And $odd \times odd = odd$
Why?  $(2m+1) \times (2k+1) = 4mk +2m + 2k + 1 = 2(2mk +m + k)+1$.
And $odd\times even = even$
Why?  Because $even \times anything=even$ as mentioned above.

So if $n$ is even.  Then $7n=odd \times even$ is even.  So $7n + 4 = even + even$ is even.  So $7n +4$ is even.

And if $n$ is odd then $7n = odd \times odd$ is odd.  So $7n +4 = odd + even = odd$.

If $7n+4$ is even then $7n = even - 4$ is even so $7n$ even.  We don't have rules of division but $n$ were odd we'd get $7n$ is odd which is a contradiction.

If $7n+4$ is odd then $7n = odd -4$ is odd.  So $7n$ is odd.  We can't do division but if were $n$ weve even we'd have $7n$ is even which is a contradiction.


Note.  If we were told $8n + 4$ was even we couldn't say whether $n$ is even or odd.  We know $8n =even -4$ is even.  And if $n$ is even then $8n =even\times even = even$ is just fine.  And if $n$ is odd then $8n = even \times odd = even$ is ... also just fine.
And if we were told $8n + 4$ was odd we'd  ... call they guy a liar.   $8n + 4 =odd$ means $8n = odd - 4=odd$.  But $8n = even \times n$ which has to be even and can never be odd.

While I appreciate these numerous examples I feel like I get lost in this because I can't even tell the head and tail apart in these chains of logical reasoning. "So is 7n+4 odd? 7n+4=7(2m+1)4=14m+7+4=14m+11. Is that even? Can we divide it by 2? 2m can be divided by 2. And 10 can be. But we will have a reminder of 1 as 11
is odd.
In fact.... 14m+11=2(7m+5)+1
. THat must be odd.
if 7n+4

is even then n is even."  This seems to mean that it is true if n is true and vice versa and I think that means the first 3 are right but I still even knowing the answer

and having seen these examples know that faced with a similar problem I cannot construct my own solution.

Well, the easiest is to always got the same way.  From $n$ to $7n +4$.   There are two choices for $n$.  If $n$ is even we ALWAYS get $7n + 4$ is even.  If $n$ is odd we ALWAYS get $7n +4$ is odd.  Those are the only two choices.  We can't go from $7n+4$ to $n$ because we do not have division rules. Instead we use, what in logic is called, the contrapositive.  If $7n+4$ is even there are two choices.  $n$ is even or $n$ is odd.  But if $n$ is odd we get $7n+4$ is even.  So that's impossible.  So $n$ is even is our only choice. $7n+4$ is even $\implies n$ is even.

The choices are:

"If $n$ is even, then $7n + 4$ is even; if $7n+4$ is even, then $n$ is even"
"If $n$ is odd, then $7n + 4$ is odd; if $7n+4$ is odd, then $n$ is odd"
"If $n$ is even, then $7n + 4$ is even; if $7n+4$ is odd, then $n$ is odd"
"If $n$ is odd, then $7n + 4$ is even; if $7n+4$ is $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\text{even}}$, then $n$ is odd"

(You still had a transcription error in your question when I wrote this; I have put a red box around the corrected text.)
One thing to remember about even and odd numbers is that an integer is either even or odd, never both. That is, "even" means "not odd" and "odd" means "not even" when referring to integers.
Also, since $n$ is an integer in all your statements, $7n+4$ also is an integer. Therefore all the numbers are integers.
A very useful fact about conditionals is this.
Suppose that the conditional "if $P$ then $Q$" is true. Then "if not $Q$ then not $P$" also is true.
Now let's put that all together. Suppose you are able to show that choice 1 is true.
Then you know the following is true: If $n$ is even, then $7n + 4$ is even.
Let $P$ be the statement "$n$ is even" and let $Q$ be the statement "$7n + 4$ is even".
You know that if $P$ then $Q$. Therefore you also know that if not $Q$ then not $P$.
That is,
If $7n + 4$ is not even then $n$ is not even.
This is the same as:
If $7n + 4$ is odd then $n$ is odd.
Notice that this is the first half of choice 2.
But this also says that the first half of choice 2 is the same as the second half of choice 1. So if you're having trouble with the second half of choice 1, you might try working on the first half of choice 2 instead. Find out whether either of these statements is true or false, and you will know if the other is true or false.
Choice 3 is just the first half of 1 and the second half of 2. What does that tell you about choice 3?
The first half of choice 4 says that if $n$ is odd, then $7n + 4$ is even. But the first half of choice 2 says  if $n$ is odd, then $7n + 4$ is odd. Those can't both be true statements. That is, choice 4 contradicts choice 2.
What about the second half of choice 4? Does it contradict any of the other choices?
So one way you can start on this problem is to try to prove or disprove the first half of 1, then try to prove or disprove the first half of 2.
I suggest those starting points because they look like good places to use the fact that $n$ is even if and only if $n = 2k$ where $k$ is some integer,
whereas $n$ is odd if and only if $n = 2k + 1$ where $k$ is some integer.

I honestly think my biggest problem is that it is one thing to remember a lot of different mathematical facts like odd x odd = odd and even x anything = even, and "One thing to remember about even and odd numbers is that an integer is either even or odd, never both. That is, "even" means "not odd" and "odd" means "not even" when referring to integers." I also wouldn't remember this: If 7n+4 is not even then n
is not even.
This is the same as:
If 7n+4
is odd then n is odd
The main problem is that I have no idea how to chain together mathematical statements to prove these things

I actually feel like I have an excellent understanding over propositional logic so I thought this would be easy for me but if you put a novel problem of the kind here in front of me, I still have no hope of constructing my own solution. Then one more meta level above that is to actually notate that solution in a mathematically proper way. Do I have to start all proves with  "I will show a " for it to be valid?

Can you explain why you are having trouble with these do you think?  To my mind it is impossible NOT to find this as obvious as  "if you flick a light-switch $n$ times will it be in the ON or OFF position".  Is there something obscure (maybe trying to express as algebra?) that you are missing that this isn't a simple YES/NO, ON/OFF, EVEN/ODD, BLACK/WHITE problem?

"a lot of different mathematical facts like odd x odd = odd and even x anything = even," Not to be cruel, but to my mind these should be as obvious as "if you drop something it falls down and you put you socks on before your shoes".  Even times anything is even because even can be cut in two so whatever you multiply it by can be cut in two.  Odd1 times odd 2 is odd because since odd1 can't be cut in two the whole can only be cut in two if something else is even... but odd2 is not even so it can't.
